# What do implicit transactions look like?

Tags: sqlite

I have a file with the following queries:

```
INSERT INTO artists(Name)
VALUE("Artist1");

SELECT *
FROM artists;
```

So my question is how does sqlite see it? Like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO artists(Name)
VALUE("Artist1");

COMMIT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT *
FROM artists;

COMMIT;
```

or like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO artists(Name)
VALUE("Artist1");

SELECT *
FROM artists;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: How are you executing the SQL statements?

Comment: @Shawn `.read query.sql`